# Nested VM in XenServer

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v, xenserver, citrix

I am new to XenServer. I am having problems getting nested VM to work in my environment. Here is my scenario:

I got XenServer 7.6.0 (Free version) running on a bare metal box (SuperServer 1028R-WC1R). VT-d is enabled in the BIOS.
I am running Windows 10 x64 guest VM and I'm trying to run another VM inside it using Virtualbox or Hyper-v.

So far, I've followed the following guides to enable nested VM in the guest but no luck:

[Nested Virtualization in Citrix XenServer](https://justus.berlin/2015/07/nested-virtualization-in-citrix-xenserver-6-5-sp1/)
[Enabling Nested Virtualization in Citrix XenServer](http://richsitblog.com/index.php/2015/10/12/enabling-nested-virtualization-on-citrix-xenserver/)

After enabling nested VM using these guides, the guest blue screens when I try to run the newly created nested VM using Virtualbox. While I get this error message when trying to run a newly created nested VM using hyper-v:

> The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

In Windows 10 guest VM, I checked Windows Task Manager -> Performance and I don't see the option Virtualization enabled in there.

I came cross this thread too: [Nested Virtualization in Xen](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Nested_Virtualization_in_Xen) but I wasn't able to edit the VM config file and am not sure if this is even applied to my case.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for your help.